# Using Javascript to make input box editable for exactly 3 seconds after user input

Tags: javascript, php, settimeout

I need a function to execute when the user types something into the input box. The function should make the input box uneditable for 3 seconds, before making the input box editable again. I have the function below, but it's not working at all. I'm wondering what I did wrong, and how to fix it?

```
function makeUnedit (id) {

    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById(id).readOnly = false; }, 3000);

    success:function(setTimeout) {
        document.getElementById(id).readOnly = true;  
    }

}
```

**Edit:**

This one works, but if you spam the input box, like you enter 1 input per 100 milliseconds or so, it'll override it, make the readOnly true all the time if you keep spamming it at that rate.

```
document.getElementById(id).readOnly = true;
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById(id).readOnly = false; }, 1500);
```

Comment: Your use of `success` appears to be incorrect. Are you referring to an Ajax call?

Comment: 1. `success` doesn't do anything here. 2. shift your functions the other way round. First make it readAble (without timeout), then call the setTimeout, but there set readonly true

Comment: @Jeff doesn't the OP want to do the opposite? She appears to from what I can understand.

Comment: @user3412847 you're right, I missread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
function makeUnedit (id) {

   document.getElementById(id).readOnly = true;

   setTimeout(function(){ 
       document.getElementById(id).readOnly = false; 
   }, 3000);

}
```

Note, that the function you pass as argument to `setTimeout(argument, milliseconds)` will get called after x milliseconds passed.

`success:` is a senseless parameter here and should have thrown a syntax error.

Comment: yes, I've read it. And I've changed my code too! I'm still thinking how to solve your spamming-issue..

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  function makeUnedit (id) {
    document.getElementById(id).readonly = true;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      document.getElementById(id).readonly = false;
    }, 3000);
  }
  
  document.getElementById("id").onfocus = function() { makeUnedit ("id") };
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="id"/>
```

By my reckoning, your use of the success keyword appears to be incorrect. As there is no need for such a statement anyhow, here is a solution.

```
function makeUnedit (id) {
  document.getElementById(id).readonly = true;
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById(id).readonly = false;
  }, 3000);
}
```

Add the code below for your handler:

```
document.getElementById(id).onfocus = function() { makeUnedit(id) };
```

Comment: Yes, you've tested it?

Comment: I have tested it, yes. If you spam it really really fast, it'll override it, and as long as you keep spamming it, it won't make it uneditable.

Comment: What event are you handling it with?

Comment: By using `focus` you should only pick up the event once, as shown above.

Comment: Where am I suppose to put focus? I'm using the function makeUnedit in another Javascript fucntion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91130/discussion-between-user3412847-and-jessica).